# redux saga not working with redux-toolkit with multiple sagas

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

Hi there I'm trying to implement saga with the new redux toolkit but unfortunately, it's not triggering the saga the moment I enable my new slice reducers saga.

rootSaga.ts

```
export function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(userSaga),
    fork(vehicleSaga),
    fork(locationSaga),
    fork(departmentSaga),
    fork(vehicleTypeSaga),
    fork(authSaga),
    fork(materialSaga),  <---- others are normal old redux sagas.
    fork(workTypeSaga),  <----- Slice saga make with createSlice.
  ]);
}
```

The moment I remove the workTypesaga from the below code it works normally. And when pass workTypeSaga directly to sagaMiddleware.run() it also worked. But multiple sagas like this is not working.

I know there is an issue with combining multiple sagas and running with the toolkit. But do have any solution for now?

edit:
Here is the workTypesaga.ts file. Yes, it is very long.

```
import { put, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";
// import {
//   getWorkTypesStart,
//   getWorkTypesSuccess,
//   getWorkTypesError,
//   createWorkTypeStart,
//   createWorkTypeSuccess,
//   createWorkTypeError,
// } from "@toilcrew/common/reducers/slices/workTypeSlice";
import * as WorkTypeSlice from "@toilcrew/common/reducers/slices/workTypeSlice";
import { routes } from "../config";
import apiService from "../services/common.services";
import commonServices from "../services/common.services";
import { selectWorkTypePageNo } from "../selectors/workType.selector";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function* getMultipleWorkTypeSaga(action) {
  console.log("action", action);
  const params = {
    method: "get",
    // route: `${routes.workType}?order_by=v_id&${addQueries}`,
    route: routes.workType,
    data: action.payload,
  };

  try {
    const res = yield commonServices(params);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.getWorkTypesSuccess(res));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.getWorkTypesError(error));
    console.log(error.response.data);
  }
}

function* createWorkTypeSaga(action) {
  console.log("action", action.payload);
  const params = {
    method: "post",
    // route: `${routes.workType}?order_by=v_id&${addQueries}`,
    route: routes.workTypeBulk,
    data: action.payload,
  };

  try {
    const res = yield apiService(params);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.createWorkTypeSuccess("message.vehicleCreated"));
    // const pageno = yield select(pagenoSelector);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.getWorkTypesStart(1));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.createWorkTypeError(error));
  }
}

function* getSingleWorkTypeSaga({ payload }) {
  console.log("getWorkTypeSaga - payload: ", payload);

  const params = {
    method: "get",
    route: `${routes.workType}/${payload}`,
  };

  try {
    //@ts-ignore
    const workType = yield call(commonServices, params);
    console.log("from update sage", workType);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.getSingleWorkTypeSuccess(workType));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error?.response?.data);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.getSingleWorkTypeError(error?.response?.data));
  }
}

function* updateWorkTypeSaga({ payload }) {
  console.log("getWorkTypeSaga - payload: ", payload);

  const params = {
    method: "patch",
    route: routes.workType,
    data: payload,
  };

  try {
    //@ts-ignore
    const vehicle = yield call(vehicleServices, params);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.updateWorkTypeSuccess("message.updateSuccess"));
    const pageno = yield useSelector(selectWorkTypePageNo);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.updateWorkTypeError(pageno));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error?.response?.data);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.updateWorkTypeError("error.500Message1"));
  }
}

function* toggleSingleWorkTypeStatusSaga({ payload }) {
  console.log("toggleWorkTypeSaga - payload: ", payload);

  const params = {
    method: "patch",
    route: `${routes.workType}/${payload.wt_id}`,
    data: payload,
  };

  try {
    //@ts-ignore
    const vehicle = yield call(vehicleServices, params);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.updateWorkTypeSuccess("message.updateSuccess"));
    const pageno = yield useSelector(selectWorkTypePageNo);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.getWorkTypesStart(pageno));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error?.response?.data);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.updateWorkTypeError("error.500Message1"));
  }
}

function* deleteSingleWorkTypeSaga({ payload }) {
  console.log("deleteworkTypeSaga - payload: ", payload);

  const params = {
    method: "delete",
    route: `${routes.workType}/${payload}`,
    // data: payload,
  };
  console.log("delete url: ", params.route);
  try {
    //@ts-ignore
    const vehicle = yield call(commonServices, params);
    yield put(
      WorkTypeSlice.deleteSingleWorkTypeSuccess("message.deleteSuccess")
    );
    const pageno = yield useSelector(selectWorkTypePageNo);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.getWorkTypesStart(pageno));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error?.response?.data);
    yield put(WorkTypeSlice.deleteSingleWorkTypeError("error.500Message1"));
  }
}

function* workTypeSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(WorkTypeSlice.createWorkTypeStart.type, createWorkTypeSaga);
  yield takeLatest(
    WorkTypeSlice.getWorkTypesStart.type,
    getMultipleWorkTypeSaga
  );
  yield takeLatest(
    WorkTypeSlice.getSingleWorkTypeStart.type,
    getSingleWorkTypeSaga
  );
  yield takeLatest(WorkTypeSlice.updateWorkTypeStart.type, updateWorkTypeSaga);
  yield takeLatest(
    WorkTypeSlice.toggleSingWorkTypeStatusStart.type,
    toggleSingleWorkTypeStatusSaga
  );
  yield takeLatest(
    WorkTypeSlice.deleteSingleWorkTypeStart.type,
    deleteSingleWorkTypeSaga
  );
}

export default workTypeSaga;
```

Comment: Include the code for `workTypeSaga` in your question.

Comment: It's hard to guess what's going wrong. Are you sure there's no uncaught error from your workTypeSaga? There might be something that only happens when running both your new and old sagas together. One think you can try is using `spawn` instead of `fork` in the root saga, and see if that changes anything. https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RootSaga#keeping-the-root-alive

That might not fix an underlying bug, but it could help with diagnosing/identifying what's happening.

Comment: well, here is the error i got from using spawn.
Tasks cancelled due to error:
takeLatest(workType/createWorkTypeStart, createWorkTypeSaga)
logError @ io-6de156f3.js?5a59:112

Comment: That error would also happen with fork. There should be some more information with the error, right? Make sure you pass valid arguments to takeLatest. You can also add some try-catch blocks in your sagas to catch errors before they bubble up to parent sagas.

Answer (score 0):

Those who're facing the same issue, I can confirm that saga and toolkit works flawlessly with each other. If you're facing such errors try to debug ur saga thoroughly. If it has any error it will stop the saga from executing. Also thanks to @Håken Lid u can use the spawn function to find any errors.

I've Found The solution. It was my bad the
`toggleSingWorkTypeStatusStart` in `WorkTypeSlice.toggleSingWorkTypeStatusStart.type` should be `toggleSingleWorkTypeStatusStart.` I've done it and its working good now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).